# MySQL join with multiple tables without subquery approach

Tags: mysql

I have the query in the fiddle as follows.

```
select * from notification where status = 0 and (
 notif_id in (select notif_id from notif_user where user_id = 1) OR 
 notif_id in (select notif_id from notif_group where group_id = 1))
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cad284e77218eb37461e60b6308bf85f

The query works as expected. But, will there be any performance issues with the query. Is it possible to convert the inner query with Join?

Comment: I would not use joins in this case as 1) you do not select data from the tables in the subqueries, only use them to restrict the selected rows 2) since the two subqueries used in an `or` operation, you would need to use left joins and make sure at least one of the joined values are non-null

Comment: (Aside: please refrain from adding thanks or other conversational items to posts here. Technical writing is generally preferred. Comments are more free-flowing and ephemeral. Thank you).

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could express the subquery as a union and compare the execution plan statistics. Looking at the output in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a9695c40bdc82ea8fc4179283e022e6), the *union* seems to perform slightly better.

```
select * 
from notification 
where status = 0 and (
 notif_id in (
    select notif_id from notif_user where user_id = 1 union all
    select notif_id from notif_group where group_id = 1
  )
);
```

Another way of expressing this would be using *exists*

```
select * 
from notification n 
where status = 0 and
(
  exists (select * from notif_user nu where nu.user_id = 1 and nu.notif_id = n.notif_id)
  or exists(select * from notif_group ng where ng.group_id = 1 and ng.notif_id = n.notif_id)
);
```

Comment: Here, select notif_id from notif_user where user_id = 1 might return all the ids the user is assigned to and it might be more than 100 thousands. Finally, the filter status = 0 might bring that down to less than 100. Still your query is a better way?

Comment: @user1578872 Additional option is with *exists* - see [modified fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a9695c40bdc82ea8fc4179283e022e6), the final exists query has the most compact plan

Answer (score 0):

Your subqueries are not dependent subqueries, they're independent. That is, they don't refer to columns in your `notification` table, only to columns in their own tables.

So there's no performance problem here.

Comment: Here, select notif_id from notif_user where user_id = 1 might return all the ids the user is assigned to and it might be more than 100 thousands. Finally, the filter status = 0 might bring that down to less than 100. Still your query is a better way?